# slideDown doesn't work

Tags: jquery, slidedown

i can't get the slideDown function to work and i can't get why, nothing happen when i hover the mouse in "école" menu item.

html code:

```
<body>
  <div id="background_bleu">
  <div id="global">
  <header> 
    <div id="block_search">
    <img id="search" src="image/search.png"> 
    <input id="input_search" type="search"/>
    <input id="go" type="button" value="Go"/>    <p id="title_search">   
    Advance Search</div>
  <menu id="menu1">
  <ul id="nav"> 
     <li> <a href="#"> Accueil </a> </li>
     <li> <a href="#"> L'école </a>
       **<ul>
          <li> <a href="#"> Qui sommes-nous ? </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">L'équipe pédagogique </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Espace parent </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Réglement intérieur </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Tarifs </a></li>**
      </ul>
     </li>
     .....
```

and the jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu1 #nav li').hover(function(){
    function(){
        $('ul').slideDown();
    },
    function(){
        $('ul').slideUp(); }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this script in order it to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu1 #nav li').hover(function(){
        $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown();
    },function(){
        $('ul', this).slideUp();
    });
});
```

And the CSS code:

```
#menu1 #nav ul { display: none; }
```

In the script when you use `$('ul', this)` it means the child ul of the parent of the event (hovering).

Answer (score 0):

Your [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method call has a few too many functions in it. At most it will accept two function arguments.

Also, you will find that all `ul` elements on your page will slide up and down. You'll need to filter by finding `ul` elements that are decendants of the current `hover` call.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu1 #nav li').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
    }
  );
});
```

```css
#nav ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<menu id="menu1">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">L'école</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Qui sommes-nous?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">L'équipe pédagogique</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Espace parent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Réglement intérieur</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tarifs</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</menu>
```